# DropdownMenuItem from SQFLite using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, sqflite

I've seen other similar topics but it didn't help me. I'm not a programmer or have a strong background on this field, just a mechanical engineer trying to develop some apps ;)

So, here's the thing, when I use dropdownmenu, i usually define a list with the items beforehand, like the below:

```
  List<String> varfluid = ["CO2", "O2"];
  String _varfluid = "CO2";

  void metFluid(String value){
    setState((){
      _varfluid=value;
    });
  }
```

This is defined before, and the below is how I create my DropdownButton

```
                    new DropdownButton(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        metFluid(value);
                      },
                      value: _varfluid,
                      items: varfluid.map((String value){
                        return new DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value),
                        );

                      }).toList(),
                    )
```

It is working fine for me so far, the challenge I'm facing now is to populate another DropDown with items from a sqflite db. I tried to do it in a similar way to the above but I'm getting an error. Here's what I have:

This is the method for returning a list with all the items from the DB

```
  Future<List> pegarTanques() async {
    var bdCliente = await db;
    var res = await bdCliente.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tabelaTanque");
    return res.toList();
  }
```

Then I run this piece of code to get only the desired property of the object to my List.

```
  List todosTanques;

  List<String> nomestanques = [""];
  String _nomestanques = "";

 void listartanques() async {
    var db = new BD();

    todosTanques = await db.pegarTanques();

    for (int i = 0; i < todosTanques.length; i++) {
      Tanque tanque = Tanque.map(todosTanques[i]);
      nomestanques.add(tanque.nome);
    }
  }
```

And then I'm getting the list just fine. However when I try to implement it the same way as I did with the dropdown with predefined items, everytime I click on an item from the dropdown list I get this error:

```
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 620 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/Victor/AndroidStudioProjects/formv3/lib/main.dart:9:14
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Showing the code in context would be more useful. But it sounds like you might want to set up a default value to the retrieved list and append to it. A close reading of the error appears to suggest it's not happy seeing a null value at some point. A classic case of a race condition. Show the full code in context and we'll be able to suggest an answer.